# Android after locale change (language), drawables doesn't update

Tags: android

My app supports two languages and user can change it in runtime. I have Utils class, with method:

```
public static void changeLocale(Activity context, String lang) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        // Change locale settings in the app.
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = new Locale(lang.toLowerCase());
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }
```

after calling this method from Activity, I call finish() method too..

```
if (changed) {
            Utils.changeLocale(this, Settings.getStringProperty(Settings.APP_LANGUAGE, ""));
            setResult(LANG_CHANGED);
        }

        finish();
```

after changing language, all Strings change successfully, but I also need to change some drawables... My activity has method initContnet():

```
private void initContent() {
        System.out.println("lang: " + Settings.getLanguage());

        setContentView(R.layout.main_navigation);
        buttons.put(TAB_1, findViewById(R.id.btn1));
        buttons.put(TAB_2, findViewById(R.id.btn2));
        buttons.put(TAB_3, findViewById(R.id.btn3));
        buttons.put(TAB_4, findViewById(R.id.btn4));
        buttons.put(TAB_5, findViewById(R.id.btn5));

        // set click listener
        Collection<View> btns = buttons.values();
        for (View v : btns) {
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        makeDefaultselection();
    }
```

and language is detected correctly (when I change language, that changed language is printet). Besides, all strings are transalted... but drawables stay same, untiil I close application and run it again (after that drawables change too).

is there any method to manually refresh all drawables?

just to be clear here are fragmetns from main_navigation.xml files:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_back"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/templates_btn_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

and here is butn_selector which points to drawable that i want to refresh:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/templates_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/templates"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: probably you are using common drawable files and separate string files for each language, add different drawable folders, like drawable-[language code].
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: `My app supports two languages and user can change it in runtime.` - there are OS settings for that, don't do it in your app.

Comment: @ArunShankar - thank you so much, I had separate values and drawable-[phone size] (like: drawable-ge-hdpi and drawable-hdpi) folders, but common drawable folder where I had selector files.. I just copied those selector xml files into drawable-ge folder and problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably you are using common drawable file and separate string files for each language.http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

**Add seperate image resourse for different languages like**

```
res-> drawable-en-> templates_selected.png
res-> drawable-ar-> templates_selected.png
res-> drawable-fr-> templates_selected.png
```

Comment: thank you so much, I had separate values and drawable-[phone size] (like: drawable-ge-hdpi and drawable-hdpi) folders, but common drawable folder where I had selector files.. I just copied those selector xml files into drawable-ge folder and problem solved

Comment: What if I have already different drawables for day and night mode ? How would I name my folders then ?